# Onclick, background image and music change. However, music keeps playing in parallel. What is the efficient way to do it for 20 music files?

Tags: javascript

Currently working on a relaxing-music app. I tried the below but the background music keeps playing when selecting a new one. What is the efficient way to do it for multiple files? I have added 2 only for example.

```
document.getElementById('winter').onclick =  function changeBackground() {
document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('winter.jpg')"
        var audio = new Audio('winter.mp3');
        audio.play();
        audio.loop = true;
}
document.getElementById('fall').onclick =  function changeBackground() {
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('fall.jpg')"
}
document.getElementById('spring').onclick =  function changeBackground() {
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('spring.jpg')"
    var audio = new Audio('spring.mp3');
    audio.play();
}
document.getElementById('summer').onclick =  function changeBackground() {
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('summer.jpg')"
    Audio.pause();
    var audio = new Audio('summer.mp3');
    audio.play();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The music keeps playing because you're simply not preventing that. You need to pause every song before playing the song you want and to do that, you need to store you Audio objects in an object, and after every event, you need to loop through all the Audios, pause them and then restart the audio you want to play. It should look something like this :

```
const songs = {
    winter: new Audio('winter.mp3'),
    spring: new Audio('spring.mp3'),
    summer: new Audio('summer.mp3'),
}

function changeBackground(background) {
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = background
}

function changeBackgroundAndSong(background) {
    for (let song in songs) {
        song.pause()
    }
    changeBackground(background)
    songs[background].currentTime = 0;
    songs[background].play()
}

document.getElementById('fall') = fall.addEventListener('click', changeBackground.bind(this, fall.id))
document.getElementById('winter') = winter.addEventListener('click', changeBackground.bind(this, winter.id))
document.getElementById('spring') = spring.addEventListener('click', changeBackground.bind(this, spring.id))
document.getElementById('summer') = summer.addEventListener('click', changeBackground.bind(this, summer.id))
```

And then to do that with several backgrounds, you should give you backgrouds one same class and do a query selectorAll and then do the same job by looping through them:

```
const backgrounds = [...document.querySelectorAll('.backgrounds')];

backgrounds.forEach(backgroundEl => {
    if(backgroundEl.id === 'fall') backgroundEl.addEventListener('click', changeBackground(this, backgroundEl.id))
    else backgroundEl.addEventListener('click', changeBackgroundAndSong.bind(this, backgroundEl.id))
})
```